# Bullet's are getting changed when I export QnA maker data through powershell

Tags: json, powershell, command-line-interface, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to export data from QnA maker using QnA maker cli and powershell script to save it to local device. When I am trying to export the data bullet's in QnA pair are converted in json file

I am using this in my script `ConvertTo-Json -depth 50`

```
$QnAMakerFAQId = Read-Host 'Please enter the KB id of FAQ QnA maker of cognitive service'
$jsonRepresentation | qnamaker export kb --kbId $QnAMakerFAQId --environment "prod" | ConvertTo-Json -depth 50| Out-File "QnAMakerFAQ.json"
```

Expected result:

```
{
      "id": 101,
      "answer": "•Sample Text1\n\n•Sample Text2",
      "source": "Editorial",
      "questions": [
        "training"
      ],
      "metadata": [],
      "alternateQuestions": "",
      "alternateQuestionClusters": []
},
```

Actual result:

```
{
      "id": 101,
      "answer": "ΓÇóSample Text1\n\nΓÇóSample Text2",
      "source": "Editorial",
      "questions": [
        "training"
      ],
      "metadata": [],
      "alternateQuestions": "",
      "alternateQuestionClusters": []
},
```

Comment: What happens when you add the encoding? `Out-File -Encoding utf8`

Comment: I tried encoding and decoding it. It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the Windows PowerShell v5 (for me) console window. PowerShell Core (v6) doesn't seem to have this problem.

Running the qnamaker command to the console (just `qnamaker export kb --kbId $QnAMakerFAQId --environment "prod"`), will out put it fine:

```
{
      "id": 96,
      "answer": "•Sample Text1 •Sample Text2",
      "source": "Editorial",
      "questions": [
        "What about testing?"
```

But as soon as you put it in a variable or try to pipe it, it will convert it.

Oddly, just pasting the text with the bullets, doesn't even seem to display them:

```
$testing = "Sample Text1 Sample Text2"
```

But in PowerShell Core v6 (or even bash) has no issues:

```
$testing = "•Sample Text1 •Sample Text2"
```

This doesn't seem to be a qnamaker issue, but a PowerShell/console issue.

Encoding for Out-File won't matter if it gets messed up before that step. (I tested it and it didn't work).

Comment: It did not solve the issue again the the output is same as the previous version.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I've tried a few different things, but no luck yet.

Comment: Thank you for taking such interest. I am also trying If i get any answer I will post it below.